# Render props in a loop NextJS

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm trying to render the props in a loop (a forEach function), but I haven't figure out how to :(

This is what I have so far:

```
{console.log('the catalog inside the component ----->', catalog)}
{Object.keys(catalog).forEach(key => {
    return (
        <div className='flex flex-col'>
            <p className='ml-12 mt-12'>`${key}`</p>
            <div className='flex justify-center items-center flex-wrap'>
            {catalog[key].forEach(item => {
                return (
                    <Image src={`/${key}/${item}`} width={150} height={150} alt={`${item}`} onClick={enlarge} className='cursor-zoom-in m-4' />
                )
            })}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
})}
<p>{catalog.Marca1[0]}</p>
```

Here's what the catalog looks like:

```
the catalog inside the component -----> {
  Marca1: [ 'gafas1.png', 'gafas2.png', 'gafas3.png', 'gafas4.png' ],
  Marca2: [ 'gafas1.png', 'gafas2.png', 'gafas3.png', 'gafas4.png' ],
  Marca3: [ 'gafas1.png', 'gafas2.png', 'gafas3.png', 'gafas4.png' ],
  Marca4: [ 'gafas1.png', 'gafas2.png', 'gafas3.png', 'gafas4.png' ]
}
```

The last line does render in the page. I just added it for testing:

`<p>{catalog.Marca1[0]}</p>`

The whole project is here:
https://github.com/Tezcatlipoca0000/paver

I am teaching myself how to code, so I will have a lot of mistakes.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Usually you would use `map` instead of `forEach` in the context of JSX.

Comment: catalog.Marca1[0] seem to only be accessible in the loop but looking at the curly bracket that p tag is outside the for loop. (I guess you have 2 loops but it's in neither)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because foreach does not return values (it returns undefined):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#return_value

You have to change the forEach method with map method which returns an array

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#return_value

Code: not tested, only modify forEach methods with map methods

```
{Object.keys(catalog).map(key => {
  return (
      <div className='flex flex-col'>
          <p className='ml-12 mt-12'>`${key}`</p>
          <div className='flex justify-center items-center flex-wrap'>
          {catalog[key].map(item => {
              return (
                  <img src={`/${key}/${item}`} width={150} height={150} alt={item} onClick={enlarge} className='cursor-zoom-in m-4' />
              )
          })}
          </div>
      </div>
  )
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array#forEach` returns `undefined`. Use `Array#map` instead to transform an array.

```
{Object.keys(catalog).map(key => (
    <div className='flex flex-col'>
        <p className='ml-12 mt-12'>`${key}`</p>
        <div className='flex justify-center items-center flex-wrap'>
        {catalog[key].map(item => (
            <Image src={`/${key}/${item}`} width={150} height={150} alt={`${item}`} onClick={enlarge} className='cursor-zoom-in m-4' />
        ))}
        </div>
    </div>
))}
```